# Spots on Calathea

Tags: houseplants

I have some yellow spots on my Calathea. When I first bought it it was wrapped in plastic so I didn’t realize it was infested with aphids. I removed the soil and dipped all the leaves and stems in Pine Sol, planted it in fresh soil and set the plant in quarantine for a week. Haven’t seen the aphids since, but now I see these yellow spots, still no aphids though. What can it be? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: These spots look like fungus infection.

Answer (score 2):

These are likely points on the leaf surface that were punctured (mechanically or otherwise) sufficiently to allow the dipping solution you used to soak into the softer interior leaf tissues and burn them. I would not worry too much about it, eventually the leaves will pass their expire by date and you will have a clean plant again.